# Triple integral over a region in space

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to determine the following integral

$$ \iiint_K xyz \, dxdydz \qquad , \qquad K=\bigl\{(x,y,z): x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1 \, \, \, , \, \, \, x^2+y^2 \leq z^2 \leq 3x^2+3y^2 \, \, , \, \, x,y,z>0 \bigr\} $$

So I integrated with respect to $z$ first

$$ \iint \, xy \, \biggl(  \int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{3(x^2+y^2)} \, dz \, \biggr) \, \, dxdy \quad=\quad \iint \, xy(2x^2+2y^2) \, dxdy $$

and then used polar coordinates

$$ x=r\cos(\theta) \quad,\quad y=r\sin(\theta) \quad \longrightarrow J=r$$

With help of the inequalities I got the boundaries for $r$ and $\theta$

$$ x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 1 \quad \longrightarrow \quad x^2+y^2 \leq 1-z^2$$

And since $ x^2+y^2 \leq z^2 \leq 3x^2+3y^2 $ i got

$$ 1 - (3x^2+3y^2) \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 1- (x^2+y^2) $$
$$\frac{1}{4} \leq x^2+y^2 \leq \frac{1}{2} $$

And since $x,y,z>0$ the angle should be from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, now integrating

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} r \cdot r \cos(\theta) \cdot r \sin(\theta) \cdot 2r^2 \, \, dr d\theta \quad=....=\quad \frac{7}{768} $$

But apparently the answer is wrong! Can anyone see what did I miss? Would appreciate to know what I did wrong since I'm pretty sure of my method(I used to in many other problems)

Comment: it's a little difficult to understand what you did, try to add more details for your steps. what Jacubian did you use?

Comment: Just updated with a more detailed soultion!

Comment: Surely the innermost integral is$$\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\min\left\{\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\right\}}dz=\min\left\{\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\right\}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

Comment: Have you considered converting to spherical? It's must easier to establish the bounds in spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geometry of the integration region is more intricate than suggested by your calculation.

Your lower bound on $z$ is okay, but the upper bound is incorrect. The non-linear constraints defining the integration region give the two upper bounds

(1) $z \le \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}$

and

(2) $z \le \sqrt{ 3 (x^2 + y^2)}$

on $z$.

So, $z$ is bounded by $\min \{ \sqrt{ 1 - x^2 - y^2}, \sqrt{3 (x^2 + y^2)} \}$. Which of the two upper bounds will be active, depends on how large $x^2 + y^2$ is. If $x^2 + y^2$ is close to $1$, the first bound is tighter, while for $x^2 + y^2$ close to $0$, the second bound is tighter.

If you want to use your approach, you would probably have to split your integral into two by making a case distinction on the value $x^2 + y^2$.

Alternatively, you might try using a different approach. Spherical coordinates might help.

Comment: I see! So I tried spherical coordinates as you said and got the right answer! I just want to know if there is any way I can see which method to use from the beginning? Like how would I know that the method I used below is not the best? Thanks for ur help sir!

Comment: You are welcome! The basic idea in the choice of coordinates is the desire to express the conditions by which your region is defined more easily in the coordinates you want to use. In your case, the expression $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ is the squared distance of $(x,y,z)$ to $0$ and $x^2 + y^2$ is the squared distance of $(x,y,z)$ to the $z$-axis, both expressible concisely in the spherical coordinates. In any case, one usually first tries to understand and/or visualize the shape of the integration region, which gives clues on what to  do (split region into pieces, use some coordinates etc.).